# How to move from "android.app.Fragment" to "android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on Facebook integration for my application. All of the fragments I am currently using in my application, as per client requirement, is
`android.app.Fragment`. Now, the Fragment we created for Facebook is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. If we convert it into `android.app.Fragment`, the functionality `loginButton.setFragment(this);` shows error.

My question is, How can I move from `android.app.Fragment` to
`android.support.v4.app.Fragment` as this piece of code is giving error:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame,new MainFragment())
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

The  error it shows is:

> Wrong 2nd argument type. Found:
>   'com.nicklodean.nicklodean.fragment.MainFragment', required:
>   'android.app.Fragment'

Please suggest how can I sort out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need in your Gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.Y.Z'
```

For the respective SDK `XX.Y` version you have.

(Really only need the v4 library, but v7 shouldn't hurt)

---

I can't help you with `loginButton.setFragment(this)` because I do not know what that is doing... But, you of course need to change the class parameter/import of your `loginButton` class.

Assuming you are using `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity`, you need to use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Personal opinion: You should be having callbacks to the Activity from the fragments to manage the FragmentManager ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments#13701071)), not directly pulling it from the Fragment classes using `getActivity()`

Comment: to use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), I need to change my app.fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment, and I cannot do that cause it is out of requirement

Comment: Then your requirements are conflicting with your code. You asked how to use v4 Fragments, and this is how you do it

Answer (score 0):

just add these dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Comment: Why version 18? And the `v7` include `v4`, so just need the second one

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (oldFragment == null) {
        ft.add(yourfragment,YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else if (!oldFragment.isAdded()) {
        ft.remove(oldFragment);
        ft.add(yourfragment,YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Comment: Not helpful cause I have to have "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment" to use "getSupportFragmentManager()". and that I cannot do because I have to use "android.app.Fragment" here.

Comment: try to put android.support.v4.app before declare fragment:
android.support.v4.app.Fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAGMENT_TAG);

Comment: also before FragmentTransaction but android.support.v4.app :
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Answer (score 0):

You simply *must* use the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` with any `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, and the `android.app.FragmentManager` with any `android.app.Fragment`. There is no way around this.

If you need to use both versions of the `Fragment` class together (in a single `Activity`), you will have to manage the fragments within each `FragmentManager` separately. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28164583/5115932) to see how to do so.